# using beautiful soup to print react text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to print out text using beautiful soup

The HTML Code is as follows:

```
<span class="C($tertiaryColor) Fz(12px) smartphone_Fz(xs)" data-reactid="42" xpath="1"><span data-reactid="43">Before hours:</span><!-- react-text: 44 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 45 -->7:49AM EDT<!-- /react-text --></span>
```

I've tried many ways but I cant seem to print the 'Before hours:' & '7:49AM EDT'.

Edit: Here's what I tried

```
SpanTag = self.StockHttmlPageSoup.find_all("span",class_ ="C($tertiaryColor) Fz(12px) smartphone_Fz(xs)")
SpanText = SpanTag.find_all('span')
print(SpanText.find(string=True))
```

Edit:
[image]

The link to the site is: https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example in your original post the following works fine.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = "<span class="C($tertiaryColor) Fz(12px) smartphone_Fz(xs)" data-reactid="42" xpath="1"><span data-reactid="43">Before hours:</span><!-- react-text: 44 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 45 -->7:49AM EDT<!-- /react-text --></span>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")

print(soup.find("span", attrs={"class":"C($tertiaryColor) Fz(12px) smartphone_Fz(xs)"}).text.strip())
```

Output : `Before hours: 7:49AM EDT`

If there are multiple `<span>` elements with the classes `C($tertiaryColor) Fz(12px) smartphone_Fz(xs)`, you may wish to run

```py
results = soup.findAll("span", attrs={"class":"C($tertiaryColor) Fz(12px) smartphone_Fz(xs)"})
```

To return a list of all such tags to the `result` variable for further processing. The inner text of each element can be accessed using the `.text` attribute e.g. `results[0].text`. The `.strip()` function can be applied to the text returned to remove any leading/trailing whitespace e.g. `results[0].text.strip()`.

**Important note:** The above does not address issues surrounding exception handling or cases in which no element is returned by `soup.find()`/`soup.findAll()`, this is to best maintain focus on the question being asked. It is obviously very important that you write your code as to account for these cases should they occur.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the problem is that, the html code i gave was for a companies stock, so for a different companies stock the html code ```</span><!-- react-text: 44 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 45 -->7:49AM EDT<!-- /react-text -->``` wont be the same

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a selection of such tags as they appear in the HTML response? Without seeing how these differ from your original example I can't really provide any advice on how to parse them.

Comment: @coderoftheday Apologies for the delayed response - been away from home. Thanks for providing the further example. I've had a look at it and tested your example with the code from my original answer and it is working fine as expected - i.e. printing `After hours: 21 Aug, 7:47PM EDT`. Since the code specifying before/after hours is contained within a `<span>` tag with the same class attributes, you can just run the code in my original answer and it will output whichever is present within the response (before or after hours). Please note that this does not cover error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this without "span"?

```
SpanTag = self.StockHttmlPageSoup.find_all(class_="C($tertiaryColor) Fz(12px) smartphone_Fz(xs)")
```